# Detecting Key Loggers

Tags: passwords, malware, audit

We know that key loggers are the most effective and most annoying means of getting compromised over login id/password on the web or any application....  and your whole privacy is breached.

Is there a way to detect key loggers yourself, instead of relying on an anti-virus solutions for this purpose ? What is the logic behind a key-logger detector...  ? Do I need to write a scipt to look for log files that correspond to key strokes, or is there a better approach than this ?

Comment: Wouldn't writing "a script to look for log files that correspond to key strokes" inherently require that you also write a keylogger of your own?

Answer (score 1):

You could download or write a script such as Neuber's Spy Protector http://neuber.com/taskmanager/index.html which has an option of blocking keyboard monitoring.